# Automatic Merge svn-git?

Tags: git, svn, automerge

I have a few question.
First of all i want to know is `git` better than `subversion`?
I am using `subversion` i want to merge `trunk` to `branch` automatically  , how can i do this? If it’s impossible do i have to use `git` ? Is merging automatically a good way ?
And last question: Which one of these big companies (like **google,oracle** etc.) use or they use something else and do they `merge automatically` ?

Comment: Short answer: "No, Git is not better than Subversion".

Comment: Can i merge automaticly in Subversion

Comment: It's better to ask one question per posting to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

No, Git is not better than Subversion, it's different. Regarding auto-merges, see ["Automatic reintegration merge"](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#auto-reintegrate).

Comment: are there any disadvantages ?